# How do I get IPython 5 to work with SublimeREPL?

Tags: python, ipython, sublimetext, jupyter, sublimerepl

I followed (actually, I authored) the instructions in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MattDMo/6cb1dfbe8a124e1ca5af) in order to modify the `ipy_repl.py` file that ships with [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) in order to get it working with more recent versions of IPython at the time. However, I recently `pip` upgraded my IPython and Jupyter packages

```
pip3 install -U ipython jupyter
```

to the latest versions, and now I'm getting this error when trying to start an IPython session from Sublime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mattdmo/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py", line 66, in <module>
    embedded_shell.initialize()
  File "<decorator-gen-113>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 74, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jupyter_console/app.py", line 137, in initialize
    self.init_shell()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jupyter_console/app.py", line 110, in init_shell
    client=self.kernel_client,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py", line 252, in __init__
    self.init_prompt_toolkit_cli()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py", line 404, in init_prompt_toolkit_cli
    self.pt_cli = CommandLineInterface(app, eventloop=self._eventloop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit/interface.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.output = output or create_output()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts.py", line 124, in create_output
    ansi_colors_only=ansi_colors_only, term=term)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit/terminal/vt100_output.py", line 425, in from_pty
    assert stdout.isatty()
AssertionError
```

I did a little digging, and at some point after early February 2016, the [`prompt_toolkit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/prompt_toolkit) module came into use in `jupyter_console`. While I assume this gives some advantages to the overall project, one disadvantage is that all text interfaces communicating with `jupyter_console` must be TTYs (a rather silly requirement, IMO), which a Sublime view is not.

I was unable to find a way around this <strike>bug</strike> feature. Does anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 4):

Through a fortuitous series of events, I came upon an old Win7 VM that I hadn't used in several months, and which had not been upgraded, so the IPython REPL still worked. Through a little experimentation, I found that if I downgraded `ipython` to version 4.1.1 and `jupyter_console` to 4.1.0, everything worked fine:

```
pip3 install -U ipython==4.1.1 jupyter_console==4.1.0
```

This isn't a perfect solution, as I am unable to play with the new features of IPython 5, but it's definitely preferable to staring at tracebacks all the time. I've updated [my gist](https://gist.github.com/MattDMo/6cb1dfbe8a124e1ca5af) mentioned in the question to reflect this finding, and wanted to post this Q&A here to get the word out, but I'm still looking for a way to get IPython 5 working.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SublimeREPL, but we've added a `--simple-prompt` flag to IPython for users of Emacs' 'inferior shell' feature. Maybe SublimeREPL works like that as well? That disables prompt_toolkit and readline entirely.

Comment: @ThomasK do you know how that can be accessed programmatically? I don't know if you took a look at `ipy_repl.py` at the gist, but basically what it's doing is setting up a connection to an instance of `ZMQTerminalIPythonApp`, then using it to communicate with a kernel. Could you access the `--simple-prompt` option via a mechanism like `cfg.InteractiveShell.simple_prompt = True` or something like that?

Comment: @ThomasK I looked through the IPython docs, and used `cfg.TerminalInteractiveShell.simple_prompt = True`, but still got exactly the same error as in my question. We already set `os.environ['TERM'] = 'emacs'` to get the "inferior-shell" behavior, so I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: The traceback you show is from `jupyter_console`, not IPython. Is there a reason you need to use that? We should add a similar option to jupyter_console, but we haven't yet.

Comment: @ThomasK `jupyter_console.app` contains `ZMQIPythonTerminalApp`, which is the basis of the whole connection system. It was moved out of `IPython.terminal.console.app` starting with IPython 4.

Comment: But is there a reason you need a Jupyter connection rather than running the `ipython` interface directly?

Comment: @ThomasK no particular reason, other than that's the interface that's already been used. The point is we're trying to run IPython *inside* of the text editor, just like emacs does (sort of). Yes, I could just use a Jupyter Notebook in my browser and be done with it, but the editor connection is useful because one can transfer code from the editor to IPython for testing.

Comment: I don't mean the notebook interface. `ipython` is a terminal interface that runs Python code inside the process. `jupyter console` is a very similar terminal interface that talks to a Jupyter kernel to run code in that kernel's language. If you only want to run Python code, `ipython` tends to be more actively developed, so you're better off using that.

Comment: @ThomasK that sounds promising. If you could point me to relevant parts of the API I could use to rewrite the `ipy_repl.py` file I linked to earlier, I'd be quite thankful. Feel free to write up an answer describing it with some detail.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of what API SublimeREPL expects, but you probably want to instantiate an IPython `InteractiveShell` object. Have a look at the `do_execute` and `do_complete` methods in [ipykernel.ipkernel](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/master/ipykernel/ipkernel.py).

Answer (score 3):

I have modified your gist so it works with the most recent version of Jupyter/IPython 6.1.0.

You only need to insert the additional config
`cfg.ZMQTerminalInteractiveShell.simple_prompt = True`
somewhere between line 38 and 41.

The hack at line 68 - 73
`if os.name == "nt":`
is not necessary for me on Win 7/10. It only displays the banner twice if you don't comment it out.

The mandatory use of the `simple-prompt` option gives only limited shell functionality (e.g. no multi-line entry).
There is the option to use the IPython shell by using `IPython.terminal.ipapp.TerminalIPythonApp` instead of `jupyter_console.app.ZMQTerminalIPythonApp`. There, however, you lose the GUI event loop integration (i.e. the `%gui` magic).

Also, I couldn't figure out how to properly exit the Jupyter shell when closing the shell window in Sublime Text. Without issuing a `quit` command first, the connection file of the jupyter kernel is not deleted - who knows what else keeps running...

Answer (score 0):

I encount the same and I solved it, I also answered this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664989/sublimerepl-and-ipython/53466987#53466987).

There are 2 ways to make it, win10, conda python3.6.7, Ipython7.1.1, Sublime 3.1.1

1.Open \Packages\SublimeREPL\config\Python\**Main.sublime-menu**, find the line

```
"windows": ["python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"]
```

and change it to where your ipython.exe located, for me is

```
"windows": ["C:\Python\envs\py37\Scripts\ipython.exe"]
```

2.Just modified \Packages\SublimeREPL\config\Python\**ipy_repl.py** to 3 lines,

```
import os
# change dir to path_to_ipython.exe
os.chdir(r'C:\Python\envs\py37\Scripts')
os.system('ipython')
```

I prefer the second one, if you encount problems with first way, such as your shortcut about sublimeREPL not work (happens to me:(), try second one.